# Mysql query showing error for some reason

Tags: php, mysql, sql

For some reason, my query is getting an error in mysql, but when I take off a part of the query, it works just fine. When I take off `, wordsCount <= (5 * 1.5)` the query runs just fine. I kept looking over it again, and again, but I'm just not seeing the error. What is wrong with my query?

```
SELECT input
    ,response
    ,((responseX REGEXP '[[:<:]]can[[:>:]]') + (responseX REGEXP '[[:<:]]i[[:>:]]')) AS wordsFoundR
    ,(LENGTH(response) - LENGTH(REPLACE(response, ' ', '')) + 1) AS wordsCount
FROM allData
HAVING wordsFoundR > 0
    ,wordsCount <= (5 * 1.5)
ORDER BY wordsFoundR DESC
    ,rand()
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @JayBlanchard #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' wordsCount <= (5 * 1.5) order by wordsFoundR desc, rand() LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1

Comment: use `and` in `having` to separate the conditions instead of `,`